# Sencha fieldsets are not displayed in windows phone/internet explorer

Tags: sencha-touch-2, fieldset

I have implemented the following using sencha 2.3.1:
I have created a sencha app with the command: sencha generate app TempApp c:/TempApp
I have replaced the default app/view/Main.js by

```
Ext.define('TempApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
alias : 'widget.login',
    config: {
    id   : 'login',
    cls  : ['account-login','mobile'],
    layout:{
type : 'vbox',
align: 'center',
pack : 'center'
},
    defaults:{
     width: 240
},
    scrollable: {
        direction: 'vertical'
    },
    items:[
    // TOP TOOLBAR
    {
    xtype  : 'toolbar',
    ui     : 'dark',
    docked : 'top',
    title  : '', 
    width  : undefined
},

// FIELSDSET
{
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'login',
items:[
{
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name : 'email',
            placeHolder: 'email',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            id   : 'loginPasswordField',
            name : 'password',
            placeHolder: 'password',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            xtype  : 'checkboxfield',
            name   : 'remember',
            //hidden : true,
            label  : 'remember',
            value  : 'true',
            checked: true,
            labelWidth: '80%'
        }
]
},

//  AND BUTTONS
{
xtype : 'button',
id    : 'loginButton',
    ui    : 'confirm',
    text  : 'login',
    margin: '5',
    handler: function(button, evt){

    }
},
{
         xtype: 'button',
         id   : 'forgotButton',
    text : 'forgot password',
    margin: '5',
    handler: function(button, evt){

    }
},

// BOTTOM TOOLBAR
{
    xtype  : 'toolbar',
    ui     : 'dark',
    docked : 'bottom',
    width  : undefined
    }
    ],
        listeners: {
     initialize: function(view, options){

     }
        }
}
});
```

fieldset is not displayed in internet explorer and windows phone
I have read this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?272642 and it seems that there is a problem with fieldsets.

How can I use fieldsets with email and password fields inside in windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

First a useful tool to fix this error is the emulation tool internet explorer 11

```
F12 > Emulation > Explorer Profile > Windows Phone
```

This tool can also be useful: [Remote HTML5 debugging on Windows Phone with weinre](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/06/12/remote-html5-debugging-on-windows-phone-with-weinre/)

Finally in the stylesheet of our application located in path *touch/resources/css* comment the following attribute in **wp.css** file

```
~ div:not(.x-msgbox) .x-input-el {/ * visibility: collapse * /}
```

In the controller we can use the following code for windows phone (the picker div must have a onclick event for the browser wp disregard the input onclick of which are under the mask):

```
Ext.define('AppName.controller.ControllerName', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires: [
// ... 
],

config: {
    refs: {
        //...
    },

    control: {          
        "picker[id='PickerId']":{show:'onPickerShow'}
        //...           
    }
},

onPickerShow: function(picker,o){
    if(picker.getId()=='PickerId'){
        document.getElementById("PickerId").onclick = Ext.emptyFn;
    }
},
```